# Sending Mail using Gmail Oauth MessagingException

Tags: android, oauth, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am developing an android application to send mails , where i am using Gmail Oauth2 token for authentication, instead of asking the user for password.

I am able to get the token and authenticate, but when i try to send a mail, i am getting a
javax.mail.MessagingException: , and the mails are not getting sent.

1)Link for my [Authenticator code](http://txtup.co/tpDuw)

2)Link for my [Sender code](http://txtup.co/OdmE)

I am not sure of where i am going wrong.

Please Help! Thanks!